# How can I improve the counting of sticks in a bundle from looking at the end of the bundle?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, hough-transform

I'm using OpenCV with Python to determine how many circular objects are on an image. I already wrote a small program to do that, but it's not precise enough. It seems to detect most of the objects, but I want a higher accuracy than this.

Any idea how to improve it's precision? Maybe a better method to detect all the (circular) objects in the images?

Changing the values don't seem to help much except the `C` parameter of the `adaptiveThreshold` function, but it is not enough.

All the images are similar or exactly like these:
[image1](https://i.imgur.com/fclXfI9.jpeg), [image2](https://i.imgur.com/k6iJWfi.jpg)

Code:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("sticks01.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 355, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 8)
gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(threshold, (3, 3), sigmaX=2.0, sigmaY=2.0)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gauss, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, minDist=50, dp=1, param1=150, param2=15, minRadius=25, maxRadius=40)

# draw detected circles on image
for (x, y, r) in circles[0, :, :]:
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (0, 255, 0), 4)

print(len(circles[0]))

cv2.imshow('image', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: seems difficult to do even with advanced morphological operations. I suggest to get the whole area including the circles and dividing whole circle area to the single small circle area. At least I believe this will give a result correctly around %95-%100 percentage

Comment: this is a bundle of sticks. be specific, not abstract. -- this requires object detection. train a detector, count detections. that's what object detection is made for. -- Hough is usually useless. here it is certainly useless.

Comment: On left side @8 o'clock, some of the sticks are rectangle.

Comment: I think segmentation would be better than object detection in this case. Since the sticks are stacked very tight your bounding rectangle will include parts of other sticks which may result in lots of false detection.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz is right: Hough is not a good fit for this problem. From a quick glance, it's clear that many of the ends of the sticks are NOT circular. Hough circle fit can work for inspection of manufactured items that are very close to perfectly circular, but even then some parameter fiddling is typically necessary.

Comment: every problem becomes a nail when a beginner consumes a (heavily adsensed) blog post or youtube video that features the cursed set of algorithms: Hough, Canny, matchTemplate. ***avoid them at all costs*** until you fully comprehend why you should. "someone said so" isn't comprehension. -- segmentation would have to be instance segmentation, which requires object detection as a first step. that suggestion seems ill-advised. stick with object detection.